# JPA JPQL nested select statement

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I have a very simple join table relating two tables, to simplify the problem we can say table1 is A and table 2 is B, with a join table AB.

| A | AB | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A_id | AB_id | B_id |
| A_details | A_id_fk | B_details |
|  | B_id_fk |  |

where A_id_fk and B_id_fk are foreign keys respectively. Im trying to create a query to retrieve all rows of A that have a relation to B. So my function receives B_id as an argument, and I want to search AB to get all rows where B_id_fk == b_id, and then use search A for all rows where A_id == the A_id_fk returned from previous search.

I tested and it can be done in plain SQL using nested select like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM A 
WHERE A_ID = 
   (SELECT A_id_fk 
   from AB 
   where B_id_fk = B_id);
```

So i read the documentation for JPQL: http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.2.0/apache-openjpa-1.2.0/docs/manual/jpa_langref.html#jpa_langref_exists and tried this

```
@Transactional
    public List<A> getA(int B_id){
        TypedQuery<A> query = em.createQuery("select i from A i where i.A_id = 
            (select z.A_id_fk from AB z where z.B_id_fk = :B_ID)", A.class);
        return query.setParameter("B_ID",B_id).getResultList();
    }
```

Im really lost right now because i followed the given example in the documentation, But its giving me unable to resolve z.A_id.fk errors, is there maybe a way to do B.class nested within A.class? Im not sure what im supposed to do here.

Comment: `select i from A i join i.ab ii where ii.b = :B_ID` ?

Comment: @JorgeCampos it did not work, what do you mean by i.ab? is . an open bracket?

Comment: `SELECT A_details FROM A JOIN AB ON A_id = A_id_fk WHERE B_id_fk = :B_ID`

Comment: Tip for structure `AB_id` isn't needed `AB` can have `(A_id_fk, B_id_fk)` as a joint primary key. Exceptional circumstances may dictate otherwise, however this is the general rule for a joining table.

Comment: @danblack yeah i tried making the composite key for 2 days and gave up. If you dont mind could you write that in JPQL format, im having a hard time translating that into JPQL.

Comment: I'm not particularly familary with JPQL however [this](https://attacomsian.com/blog/spring-data-jpa-composite-primary-key) and [this](https://techrocking.com/jpa-composite-primary-key/) have similar answers.

Comment: What I meant was you must have a class A / B and / AB and each has the references right? With that you can use the JPQL A join A.AB and AB.B.id : param

Answer (score 0):

Based on your query, I assume that you mapped your entities directly (`A` with `A_id`, `A_details` fields, `B` with `B_id`, `B_details` fields, and `AB` with `AB_id`, `A_id_fk`, `B_id_fk`).

I've run a test and your query (the way you wrote it here) works as expected.

`unable to resolve z.A_id.fk` suggests you have a typo in your original code (`A_id.fk` instead of `A_id_fk`).

If you have a different model, please include the model of your entities here along with the full exception.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what ended up working:

```
TypedQuery<Promotions> query = em.createQuery("select i from A i inner join AB x on x.A.A_id = i.A_id where x.B.B_id = :B_id", A.class);
```